# Proving that if the derivative of f tends to zero as x tends to infinity, then the quotient $f(x)/x$ tends to zero as $x$ tends to infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I need to prove the following:

> If $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f'(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$.

Intuitively it's easily seen that it must be true, since the derivative being "smaller and smaller" as the argument grows indicates that the graph of the function flattens as $x \rightarrow \infty $. To prove this formally, I wanted to show that such a function f is bounded (in a neighborhood of $\infty$), since then we can say that

$$0 \leq |\frac{f(x)}{x} | \leq \frac{M}{x},$$
and we would be done by the squeeze theorem.

I tried to prove this by contradiction, relating the values of the derivative with a quotient relating f via the Mean Value Theorem.
My idea is roughly this: if f happens not to be bounded, then for $x$ and $y$ large enough, $|f(x)-f(y)|>N$, where $N$ is any positive real number, and therefore
$$|f'(z)|=\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}>\frac{N}{|x-y|}.$$

Here I'm trying to contradict the fact that for such a big $z$, $|f'(z)|$ is less than an appropriate $\epsilon$ . The problem is that nothing assures me that $|x-y|$ is a large number, making  $\frac{N}{|x-y|}$ little, wrecking my argument.

Suggestions about how to improve my argument will be very appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a natural way to rigorously argue this fact is via MVT.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f'(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, we can find $x_0>0$ such that $x>x_0$ implies $|f'(x)|<\epsilon/2$ for all $x>x_0$. Because $f(x_0)/x\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, we can find $x_1>0$ such that $\Big|\frac{f(x_0)}{x}\Big|<\epsilon/2$ for all $x>x_1$. Set $x^*=\max\{x_0,x_1\}$ and choose $x\in(x^*,\infty)$ arbitrarily. From MVT find $c\in (x^*,x)$ such that $$f(x)=f'(c)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$$ This means $$\frac{f(x)}{x}=f'(c)\Big(\frac{x-x_0}{x}\Big)+\frac{f(x_0)}{x}$$ Since $c>\max\{x_0,x_1\}\geq x_0$ we can establish that $|f'(c)|<\epsilon/2$. Moreover $x>\max\{x_0,x_1\}\geq x_0$ implies $\Bigg|\frac{x-x_0}{x}\Bigg|<1$ and we get with triangle inequality $$\bigg|\frac{f(x)}{x}\bigg|\leq |f'(c)|\cdot \bigg|\frac{x-x_0}{x}\bigg|+\bigg|\frac{f(x_0)}{x}\bigg|<\epsilon$$ and we're done.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the fact that $f'(x) \to 0$ does not imply that $f$ is bounded. As an example, consider $f(x) = \ln x$, which has $f'(x) = \frac1x$. We see that $1/x \to 0$ but $\ln x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Brace yourself; I think I've made this much longer than it has to be.

With that being said, your idea of relating the derivative of $f$ to $f$ itself via the mean value theorem is spot on. To use this idea effectively, argue by contrapositive, assuming that $f(x)/x$ does *not* approach 0. This would mean that for some $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an increasing sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \to \infty$ such that $|f(x_n)/x_n| > \epsilon$ for all $n$. We can assume without loss of generality that $x_n > 0$ for all $n$ (since $x_n \to \infty$). Rearranging then gives us
$$|f(x_n)| > \epsilon x_n$$
for all $n$.

See if you can use the mean value theorem to finish the proof from here. If you're having trouble, see below.

Solution part 1 (hint at how to employ mean value theorem):

> Note that since the sequence $(x_n)$ is infinite, so is the sequence $(f(x_n))$. This means that the sequence $(f(x_n))$ has infinitely many positive terms or infinitely many negative terms (or both). Without loss of generality, suppose that $f(x_n)$ is positive for infinitely many $n$. With that in mind, let >! $x_{n_1}$ have $f(x_{n_1}) > 0$, so
>  $$f(x_{n_1}) > \epsilon x_{n_1}$$
>  Note that for any $m > n_1$ such that $f(x_m) > 0$, we have
>  $$\frac{f(x_m) - f(x_{n_1})}{x_m - x_{n_1}} > \frac{\epsilon x_{m} - f(x_{n_1})}{x_m - x_{n_1}}$$

Solution part 2 (everything except actually using the MVT):

> As $m \to \infty$, $x_m \to \infty$, so the right hand side of this inequality approaches $\epsilon$. This means that for $m$ sufficiently large, the right hand side is greater than $\epsilon/2$. Let $n_2 > n_1$ so that when $m$ is replaced by $n_2$, the right hand side is greater than $\epsilon/2$. Now notice that for all $m > n_2$, we have
>  $$\frac{f(x_m) - f(x_{n_2})}{x_m - x_{n_2}} > \frac{\epsilon x_{m} - f(x_{n_2})}{x_m - x_{n_2}}$$
>  Again the right hand side approaches $\epsilon$, so just as before, we choose $n_3 > n_2$ such that when $m$ is replaced by $n_3$, the right hand side is greater than $\epsilon/2$. Continuing this process, we end up with a sequence $n_1, n_2, n_3, \ldots$, such that
>  $$ \frac{f(x_{n_{k+1}}) - f(x_{n_{k}})}{x_{n_{k+1}} - x_{n_k}} > \frac\epsilon2$$
>  for all $k$.

Solution part 3 (using the MVT to complete the solution):

> By the mean value theorem, this implies that for all $k \in \mathbb N$, there exists $y_k \in [x_{n_k}, x_{n_{k+1}}]$ such that $f'(y_k) > \frac\epsilon2$. Since $x_{n_k} \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$, we see that there are arbitrarily large values of $y$ such that $f'(y) > \frac\epsilon2$, which implies that $f'(y)$ does not approach 0 as $y \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$ does not imply that $f$ is bounded, just look at $\ln x$. However, your statement follows by using L'Hopitals rule. Indeed, if $f$ happens to be bounded, we are done. Otherwise, it goes off to infinity and we may compute
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f'(x)}{\partial_x x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$$
**EDIT**

My claim that $f$ not being bounded implies $f$ to infinity is not true, as pointed out in the comments (take $f(x)=\ln x\sin(\ln x)$). Despite this, the above argument can be fixed as follows: note that $f(x)=\int_0^xf'(s)\chi_{f'\ge 0}(s)\text ds+\int_0^xf'(s)\chi_{f'< 0}(s)\text ds=f^+(x)+f^-(x)$ with both $f^\pm$ being continuously differentiable and monotonic. If both are bounded we are done, otherwise, by their monotonicity, it follows that one of them most go to infinity. Now apply the previous argument and the linearity of the limit to whichever component blows up.

Comment: $f$ is not bounded does not imply $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Eg of an unbounded function which doesn't go to infinity: $x \sin x$.

Comment: @SungjinKim you are correct, I failed to see something like $\ln x \sin(\ln x)$. However, the argument can be salvaged via the monotonic decomposition $f(x)=\int_0^xf'(s)\chi_{f'\ge 0}(s)\text ds+\int_0^xf'(s)\chi_{f'< 0}(s)\text ds$.

Comment: @Kaind your example does not work because $f'$ does not vanish at infinity, however, Sungjin's comment is true.

Comment: @GuachoPerez Your edit still has a problem. $f'$ may not be Riemann integrable.

Comment: @SungjinKim it does not have to be Riemann integrable. Since $f'$ is eventually bounded and measurable, both parts of the FTC with the Lebesgue integral still hold.

Comment: @GuachoPerez I see. The decomposition makes sense now.